# Why am I getting an error with this simple scheme code?

Tags: scheme

```
(define ZERO (lambda (f x) x))    
(define ONE (lambda (f x) (f x)))
(define SUCC (lambda (n) (lambda (f x) (f (n f x)))))
(display (ZERO 1 0))
(display (ONE 1 0))
(display ((SUCC ZERO) 1 0))
```

The ZERO function works fine. When I run this code, I get an error,

> ERROR: invalid application: (1 0)

for `ONE`, `SUCC` function.

How can I fix my code to make it work?

Comment: The first argument to `ONE` has to be a function, so that you can execute `(f x)`.

Comment: E.g. `(ONE + 3)` is equivalent to `(+ 3)`

Comment: What are you expecting `(display (ONE 1 0))` to print?

Comment: I think I understand now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is the Church encoding of numbers; the number K is represented by K applications of a function `f` to some argument `x`.
(The identities of the function and that argument are, surprisingly enough, irrelevant - you can build all of mathematics without caring.)

You can make it make a bit of sense with suitable choices of `f` and `x` - try, for instance, `0` and

```
(define (inc x) (+ x 1))
```

so the number K is represented by adding 1, K times, to 0.

```
> (ZERO inc 0)
0
> (ONE inc 0)
1
> ((SUCC ONE) inc 0)
2
```

You can also add some convenience with an evaluation function:

```
> (define (number n) (n inc 0))
> (number ZERO)
0
> (number ONE)
1
> (number (SUCC (SUCC (SUCC (SUCC ONE)))))
5
```